# Alternative to .nextSibling?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a project and I have to fill different column of a table, for that I'm using `.nextSibling`, but the lines can be very long if I target, let's say the 4th column:

```
firstTd.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = "example";
```

So I was wondering if there was any more elegant way of doing it, that doesn't require writing `.nextSibling` every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a small helper:

```
 const sibling = (el, count) => count ? sibling(el.nextSibling, count - 1) : el;
```

Which can be used as

```
sibling(firstTd, 5).innerHTML = "example";
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Rather than relying on a specific position like that, which is inherently brittle (what if you add a new column?), I'd suggest giving your target `td` some kind of identifying mark, like a class name or `data-*` attribute. Then you'd use:

```
tr.querySelector(".the-class").innerHTML = "example";
```

if you don't have `tr` handy, you can get it from `firstTd.parentNode`.

Naturally, because `querySelector` doesn't just look at children but all descendants, you'll want to plan for that.

Live example:

```js
// In a real situation I'd use a delegated handler, but the goal here is to
// show that the same code works regardless of the starting point
document.querySelectorAll("td:not(.x)").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentNode.querySelector(".ex").innerHTML = Math.random();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Click me</td>
      <td>Or me</td>
      <td>Or me</td>
      <td class="ex"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternately, give yourself a "find my next matching sibling" function that accepts a selector:

```
const findNext = (el, selector) => {
    let sib = el.nextElementSibling;
    while (sib && !sib.matches(selector)) {
        sib = sib.nextElementSibling;
    }
    return sib;
};
```

then

```
findNext(firstTd, ".the-class").innerHTML = "example";
```

Live example:

```js
const findNext = (el, selector) => {
    let sib = el.nextElementSibling;
    while (sib && !sib.matches(selector)) {
        sib = sib.nextElementSibling;
    }
    return sib;
};

// In a real situation I'd use a delegated handler, but the goal here is to
// show that the same code works regardless of the starting point
document.querySelectorAll("td:not(.x)").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    findNext(this, ".ex").innerHTML = Math.random();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Click me</td>
      <td>Or me</td>
      <td>Or me</td>
      <td class="ex"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Table rows and cells can be accessed by [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows):

```js
table1.rows[2].cells[2].innerText = 42
```

```html
<table id=table1>
  <tr> <th> A </th> <th> B </th> <th> C </th> </tr>
  <tr> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> 6 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: True, and that's even [standardized](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmltablerowelement) now. But it suffers from the same britlleness problem, minor change to the markup will break it.